# Linq query Group By with contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of the List of string that is `Currency Code`.

```
var currencyCode = new List<string>() { "USD", "SGD", "KWD", "BHD", "LYD" };
```

And i Have another complex object.

```
 var rate = new List<Rate>()
 {
        new Rate() { CurrencyName = "USD (SMALL)",CurrencyCode = "USD SMALL",BranchName="Branch1"},
        new Rate() { CurrencyName = "SGD BIG",CurrencyCode = "SGD BIG",BranchName="Branch1"},
        new Rate() { CurrencyName = "KUWAIT DINAR",CurrencyCode = "KWD",BranchName="Branch1"},
        new Rate() { CurrencyName = "USD BIG (100,50)",CurrencyCode = "USD BIG",BranchName="Branch1"},
        new Rate() { CurrencyName = "USD MEDIUM (10,20)",CurrencyCode = "USD MEDIUM",BranchName="Branch1"},
  };
```

I will have the matched currency in the below list:

```
var matchedCurrency = from c in rate
                      where currency.Any(w => c.CurrencyCode.Contains(w))
                      select c;
```

What i wanted is that the matching currency list should be in grouped, grouped by currency code.

I tried by the following way but it did not worked.

```
 var Grp = rate.GroupBy(item => currency.Any(w => item.CurrencyCode.Contains(w)))
          .Select(group => new
          {
              group.Key,
              DataList = group.ToList()
           });
```

I don't get i am actually missing. I have tried by various ways.

I know i can loop through the `rate` and push into another object. But that does not look nice   i wanted to do this by using Linq. But i could not achieve the point.

Output will be displayed with this object:

```
public class CurrencyMap
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public List<Currency> currency { get; set; }
}
public class Currency
{
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
}
enter code here
```

EDIT:

I missed the things at first but  i also need to have the empty list if the matching code was not found in the rate.

In Rate there is not the matching list for "BHD", "LYD". But i also need to have the empty list with the code "BHD", "LYD"

Comment: Please include an example of expected output. I don't understand entirely what your question is, reading the already posted answers.

Comment: I will post the expect output.

Comment: Do you really need `Contains` or are all currency codes equal to the first 3 characters of `Rate.CurrencyCode`?

Comment: @grek40 yes i will need contains. The currency code in `rate` may not have the exact mapping of same currency.

Comment: If this is something you need to do frequently I would introduce a new field `CurrencyCategory` in your `Rate` (or `Currency`) class, or (better) a reference to a new `CurrencyCategory` entity.

Comment: Yes this i would do frequently. There would be mapping with several branches. and the i need to get the `rate` from external API's. Currency may changes with company. Rate Class is not under my control. I cannot change the Rate class that contains exact mapping with the API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First select the matching currency code, then group by the selected code.

```
var groupedRates = rate
    .Select(r => new
    {
        rate = r,
        code = currencyCode.FirstOrDefault(c => r.CurrencyCode.Contains(c))
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.code, x => x.rate); //maybe you don't want to throw away the resolved code like I do in the element selector...
```

Edit: I guess I was a bit to focused on the grouping aspect. Since you want to include all currency codes and mentioned a specific output structure, forget about grouping and just select your result:

```
var groupedRatesList = currencyCode
    .Select(c => new CurrencyMap
    {
         Code = c,
         currency = rate
            .Where(x => x.CurrencyCode.Contains(c))
            .Select(x => new Currency
            {
                BranchName = x.BranchName,
                CurrencyCode = x.CurrencyCode, // or maybe you want to insert c here?
                CurrencyName = x.CurrencyName
            })
            .ToList()
     })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Side note: the whole approach would of course fall apart as soon as there is (for example) a currency named `MAL` and the currency code matching finds `USD SMALL` as first result instead... possibly use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault` in order to at least detect such problems.

Comment: Is there any way to select and `map` inside the select in linq with my `CurrencyMap` and `Currency` class?

Comment: Sorry i missed the things at first but  i also need to have the empty list if the matching code was not found in the rate.

Comment: @ashwinshrestha this statement is a bit confusing... so you mean you also need the (not empty) list of rates / currencies with empty `code` if the `currencyCode` is not found?

Comment: In Rate there is not the matching list for "BHD", "LYD". But i also need to have the empty list with the code "BHD", "LYD"

Comment: Thank You! Perfect for what i needed.

Answer (score 3):

It is a rather hacky approach but you could use [Regex.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this. The basic idea is that you need the value from `currencyCode` as the key for your grouping.

This can be returned by a sucessfull match with regex. The property [Match.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value(v=vs.110).aspx) will contain the string value for the key

Disclaimer: Unfortunately all negative matches will be return also as empty groups. You would need to filter then the empty groups out:

```
var result = currencyCode.SelectMany
             (
                 x=> rate.Where(r=> r.CurrencyCode.Contains(x))
                         .GroupBy(r=> Regex.Match(r.CurrencyCode, x).Value)
             ).Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key));
```

Actually it works also without regex:

```
var result = rate.GroupBy(r => currencyCode.FirstOrDefault(c=> r.CurrencyCode.Contains(c)))
                 .Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key));
```

Disclaimer 2: Like all pattern matching it will lead to problems if you have ambiguous patterns. If a `CurrencyCode` value contains more than 1 of the abriviations ( may be inside the word ) you can get non sensical results/ or double entries.

Although I found it to be an intriguing problem to solve with linq, personally I would refrain from this approach. If I would have to return to this code after 9 months to maintain it, I would be way more happy to read this:

```
Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<Rate>> groupedSet = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Rate>>();

foreach (var key in currencyCode)
{
    IEnumerable<Rate> _result = rate.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode.Contains(key));
    if (_result.Any())
    {
        groupedSet.Add(key, _result);           
    }
}
```

than to start remembering what da hack I wrote back then and what I might have thought of when I wrote it back then....

Comment: This won't group with the currency code. And i will also want to select the currency name and branch name. Not only the currency code.

Comment: @ashwinshrestha I am not sure that I understand you. `matchedCurrency` will have groups with the key = CurrencyCode and the entire object as value. Do you have problems to extract the values from the [IGrouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx) object?

Comment: @ashwinshrestha do you want to be all `USD` in one group? like `"USD SMALL"` and `"USD BIG"` and `"USD MEDIUM"` ?

Comment: I tried your ways but it listed me the matched records from the rate. I am getting the 4 records on `matchedCurrency`.

Comment: @ashwinshrestha yes because the have all a different `CurrencyCode`. The abriviations in your `currencyCode = new List<string>()` are shorter. again: do you want to group by the matched abreviations ?

Comment: Yes. All USD in One group. Similaly all SGD in group.

Comment: @ashwinshrestha OK now I understood you. I edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Your second solutions seems the most readable solution for the problems. But there is the `dictionary`, it seems it will be extra burden to   map with the dictionary back to the Class types.

Comment: Selecting the currency code inside the `GroupBy`... ofcourse that's an even better idea than preselecting it into a new data structure :)

Comment: @ashwinshrestha "it will be extra burden to map with the dictionary back to the Class types" this was your requirement: To have the `USD` as key. It will be the same in the `IGrouping` result. the group result and the dictionary are structurally the same

Comment: Don't destroy your answer... a regex that forces space before the currency code doesn't even resolve the example from question

Comment: @grek40 thanx. One should know when it's enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way since this approach assumes you have fixed length of *Currency* but you can try this:-

```
int currencyLength = currencyCode.First().Length;
var result = rate.Where(x => currencyCode.Any(z => x.CurrencyCode.Contains(z)))
                 .GroupBy(x => x.CurrencyCode.Substring(0, currencyLength))
                 .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Currency = x.Key,
                            List = x.ToList()
                        });
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rmb6Mq)

Comment: We always cannot have the same length of currency code, the currency code may be different it depends upon how the company set the format for the code. but we can have the same types of pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var currencyCodes = new List<string>() { "USD", "SGD", "KWD", "BHD", "LYD" };

var currencies = new List<Currency>()
{
    new Currency() { CurrencyName = "USD (SMALL)",CurrencyCode = "USD SMALL",BranchName="Branch1"},
    new Currency() { CurrencyName = "SGD BIG",CurrencyCode = "SGD BIG",BranchName="Branch1"},
    new Currency() { CurrencyName = "KUWAIT DINAR",CurrencyCode = "KWD",BranchName="Branch1"},
    new Currency() { CurrencyName = "USD BIG (100,50)",CurrencyCode = "USD BIG",BranchName="Branch1"},
    new Currency() { CurrencyName = "USD MEDIUM (10,20)",CurrencyCode = "USD MEDIUM",BranchName="Branch1"},
};

List<CurrencyMap> maps = currencies.Select(c => new
                                   {
                                       Currency = c,
                                       FoundCode = currencyCodes.FirstOrDefault(code => c.CurrencyCode.Contains(code))
                                   })
                                   .Where(o => o.FoundCode != null)
                                   .GroupBy(o => o.FoundCode)
                                   .Select(grp => new CurrencyMap() { Code = grp.Key, Currencies = grp.Select(o => o.Currency).ToList() })
                                   .ToList();
```